# git rebase adds old committed files on local main

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, reset, rebase

I want to rebase my branch (say branch-a) to origin/main (Azure DevOps) when i run "git rebase origin/main" or "git rebase main" it adds about 13 files that i mistakenly committed to my local main branch.

I expect that when i run "git rebase origin/main" it should go to remote main branch and rebase it to my branch-a but this is not happening.

reading article [git hard reset](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset#:%7E:text=To%20review%2C%20git%20reset%20is,correspond%20to%20the%20three%20trees.), looks like staging index files are stuck in the cache that keeps bringing the files i committed by mistake to my local main. I'm thinking of doing "git reset --hard  but not fully understand the implications or if its the right thing to do.

Can someone please advice?

git rebase origin/main

Comment: Have you fetched the remote?

Comment: yes after you advised but makes no difference.